# Is it more efficient to Index a Date and store the time separately, or Index a single DateTime?

Tags: mysql

My web app allows users to set reminders for later. I'm curious as to the performance benefits of DateTime (stored together) VS Date and Time (stored seperatly).

That is to say, is it more efficient to store the DateTime together, or store the Date and Time separately?

Here's my thinking. If I store the Date and Time separately, I only have to index the date. Now, I can query for all reminders that are on 'todays' date, and then use the "time" column to set a timer for each result. The downside is the added complexity of parsing the Unix/Epoch time string that is coming from the client in order to get a seperate date and time.

On the other hand, it would be very convenient to store just a Unix/Epoch timestamp (We won't be setting reminders for the past anyway...). But something is screaming inside me that a DateTime index is all but useless. After all, what are the odds that two users set a reminder at the same millisecond? So my index on this column wouldn't be any smaller (or faster) than doing a table-scan, would it?

P.S. Bonus points if anyone can find an explanation of how MySQL indexes DateTimes.

Comment: Store dates and times as single entities.

Comment: It depends. If you are looking for exactitude, together is better.  For range scans, it doesn't much matter unless the size of the result set exceeds 15% or so of the data.  Index range scans are one of the things that MySQL got right, IMO.  I don't actually know how a date, datetime or timestamp are represented internally, but if I had to guess, it would be either a strict numeric, a georgian derivative or as a "text" in which case the index would be [edit because "but" makes no sense lol] more fulltext.

Comment: Really and truthfully, it's a moot point. I ended up storing and indexing the Date. And then storing the timestamp instead of the time. Now I can query for Dates that are equal to CURRENT_DATE(), and use the timestamp field to directly create a Date object in node to set my timer. It's literally the best of both worlds! Thanks for the suggestions! And thanks for the explanation @TGray